# decompiling a .class for struts

Tags: java, struts

So initially my goal is to modify MY copy of a network monitoring tool to add to its html an EXTRA option in the navigation menu so I can relocate to html.net for example when someone clicks that menu item. The tool is written in Java using struts and it took me 1 week fo searching throguh the files and folder to finally find the .class for one of the menu items named Dashboard

From the struts.config.xml I found that Dashboard.jsp is one of the menu's files....I am probably confusing you so please ignore anything that DOES confuse you...

Long story short its all in something called servlet which I am not familiar with...

So to modify the html thats in the .jsp file I have to change the .class because in the files or folders the source code isnt there so its all precompiled...I decompiled the class for Dashboard_jsp.class and got this: http://pastebin.com/UkspReDu

Now I just need help figuring out what this is because I have never worked with this before...I need to add an extra menu item or make it so when a user clicks on the Dashboard tab it relocates to html.net I dont know what line to modify here...I need help with that. Then I can recompile and replace old .class with new.

[image]

Comment: Are there any JavaScript files that the application uses? Honestly, you could just edit one of those and dynamically switch the URL for the dashboard link. It would be less painful.

Comment: YEAH!!! I find this particular line of code VERY interesting relating to what you said, its near the top where it says www.dynamicdrive.com there is a .js being added under

Comment: Or just GreaseMonkey it up, or run it inside a frame, or... But lines 136 starts one chunk of links, 238 another. Kind of hard to tell since we can't see the URLs, and the source looks like it's pulling titles from resources. Also looks like they put a bunch of Java code in the JSP :(